# Is it possible to inject WCF REST service client via castle windsor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, castle-windsor

I created two WCF rest services `service1` and `service2` hosted in separate ports and used `Castle Windsor` for dependency injection in `service1` and now from `service1` trying to call `service2`. but when I create an instance and call for the `service2`, I am getting an exception saying `bad request(400)`. When I request for `service2` from REST client I am able to get the `200 response`. Is the error due to castle Windsor lifestyle behavior?.

Container config (service 1)

```
Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>().Register(
                           Component.For(type).AsWcfClient(
                               new DefaultClientModel { 
                                       Endpoint = WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("*") }));
```

Configuration  (service 1)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8082/BLDBService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customHttpBinding" contract ="DataSourceContracts.IBLDBService" behaviorConfiguration ="serviceEndpointHttpBehavior">
  </endpoint>
</client>
<services>
  <service name="BusinessService.MetaDataService" behaviorConfiguration="basicHttpBehavior">        
    <host>
      <baseAddresses >
        <add baseAddress ="http://localhost:8084/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
   <endpoint address="MetaDataService" binding="webHttpBinding" contract ="BusinessServiceContracts.IMetaDataService" behaviorConfiguration="endpointHttpBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <!--<basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>-->
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="customHttpBinding" transferMode ="Streamed">          
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled ="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled ="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat ="Json"></webHttp>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="serviceEndpointHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled ="true" helpEnabled ="true"  />
      <dataContractSerializer/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicHttpBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Service call  (service 1)

```
_bldbService = Container.resolve<IBLDBService>();
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
viewModel = _bldbService.GetBLDBData(viewModel);
```

Configuration (Service2)

```
 <service name="BusinessService.BLDBService" behaviorConfiguration="basicHttpBehavior">
    <!--<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8082/BLDBService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="BusinessServiceContracts.IBLDBService"/>-->
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress ="http://localhost:8082/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="BLDBService" binding="webHttpBinding"    contract ="BusinessServiceContracts.IBLDBService" behaviorConfiguration="endpointHttpBehavior"/>
  </service>
```

On calling from REST Client

[image]

P.S. I have tested with net/tcp protocol and it works perfectly.

[image]

here is the log

```
        Time : 06.03.2017 11:11:15
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Message: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Environment: Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Stack Trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.InvokeRealProxy(RealProxy realProxy, WcfInvocation wcfInvocation)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfInvocation.Proceed()
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.RepairChannelPolicy.Apply(WcfInvocation wcfInvocation)
       at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Proxy.WcfRemotingInterceptor.PerformInvocation(IInvocation invocation, Action`1 action)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Castle.Proxies.IBLDBServiceProxy.GetBLDBData(MetaDataViewModel viewModel)
       at BusinessLogic.BLDBBusinessManager.GetData(MetaDataViewModel viewModel) in C:\localPTC\Sample\BasicFramework\BusinessLogic\BLDB\BLDBBusinessManager.cs:line 46
       at BusinessService.MetaDataService.GetMetaData(MetaDataViewModel metadata) in C:\localPTC\Sample\BasicFramework\BusinessService\Services\MetaDataService.cs:line 16
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Time : 06.03.2017 11:11:15
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Environment: System
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Stack Trace: at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The code you shared is of calling "Service2" from "Service1" ? Have you configured settings and container for "Service2" also? Can you share that configuration too? Did you try to debug and check if it reached to the "Service2" code at all?

Comment: @chetan-ranpariya If I call from REST client it will reach and give 200 response but I when call via Castle windsor container instance its saying bad request which means request going to the server but request type is invalid.

Comment: Do you get any other information when you get "Bad Request" response from the service, such as error information, data validation error, authorization failed etc? Also when your debugging "Service1" does it hit the line `viewModel = _bldbService.GetBLDBData(viewModel);` in "Service1" ?

Comment: updated with log details

Comment: Strange behavior. Can't see any problem at first glance. May be you might want to check the binding settings on both client application and service side are in sync and also you can enable tracing at the service end to see what is the reason behind unexpected response being sent. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

I was hardcoding Request-Reponse format for the service as JSON. now I removed it from the service contract and It's works perfectly. The new service contract and web.config looks like below.

```
namespace DataSourceContracts
{
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using ViewModel.DataSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// This is same as the exposed BLDB data REST service in abother project we need to keep both in sync. 
    /// The reason for not refering to the same project is the .Net framework version
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBLDBService : IDataSourceService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sample method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="viewModel"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",  UriTemplate = "GetBLDBData")]
        MetaDataViewModel GetBLDBData(MetaDataViewModel viewModel);
    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
  <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  defaultBodyStyle="Bare"></webHttp>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```